# Does the fall in Ether's value risk the stability of the Ethereum network in general?

Tags: ether

If the value of Ether falls substantially or possibly falls completely, what risk does that pose to the Ethereum network in general ?

If nodes on the network are paid in Ether and Ether no longer has any value, or enough value - surely there's no point in doing the work or spending the money on electricity and therefore the network would cease to exist ? (Taking NFTs and everything else with it)

Comment: That possibility exists for any currency, either fiat or crypto. If it loses so much of its value that nobody wants it then it will no longer be useful.

Comment: Of course, but the question is what happens to the Ethereum blockchain in general. Without payments of any value, would the blockchain simply cease to exist taking everything with it ?

Comment: Any blockchain will be under the same problem. If it has lost all of its value it will be subjects to majority attacks because the coin will be really cheap. This in turn will make difficult for legitime users to trust projects running on it. Then projects will migrate to more trustworthy chains. Eventually miners will stop creating blocks. Usually in blockchains like Ethereum miners could extract value other than creating blocks, so it is possible they to continue mining ,even when the price is low, because other projects pay them in a different token. Side chains for example.